# What causes the MissingRequirementError: object scala not found error in Stanford Topic Modeling toolbox?

Tags: scala, stanford-nlp, topic-modeling

Executing the code example for PLDA using Stanford Topic Modeling Toolkit tmt causes the `"scala.tools.nsc.MissingRequirementError: object scala not found"` error.

As instructed in the Stanford [TMT webpage](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tmt/tmt-0.4/), I download and run the [tmt script](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tmt/tmt-0.4/tmt-0.4.0.jar). This does launch the app. Then, I downloaded the required [data](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tmt/tmt-0.4/examples/pubmed-oa-subset.csv) that is used as input to the PLDA script. However, on executing the script for [PLDA](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tmt/tmt-0.4/examples/example-7-plda-learn.scala), it throws following error..

```
scala.tools.nsc.MissingRequirementError: object scala not found.
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Definitions$definitions$.getModuleOrClass(Definitions.scala:655)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Definitions$definitions$.getModule(Definitions.scala:605)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Definitions$definitions$.ScalaPackage(Definitions.scala:145)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Definitions$definitions$.ScalaPackageClass(Definitions.scala:146)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Definitions$definitions$.AnyClass(Definitions.scala:176)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Definitions$definitions$.init(Definitions.scala:814)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.<init>(Global.scala:697)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner.compile$1(ScriptRunner.scala:120)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner$$anonfun$withCompiledScript$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ScriptRunner.scala:157)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner$$anonfun$withCompiledScript$1.apply(ScriptRunner.scala:131)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner$$anonfun$withCompiledScript$1.apply(ScriptRunner.scala:131)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.package$.waitingForThreads(package.scala:26)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner.withCompiledScript(ScriptRunner.scala:130)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner.runScript(ScriptRunner.scala:188)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner.runScriptAndCatch(ScriptRunner.scala:201)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:58)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:80)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:89)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tmt.TMTMain$.main(TMTMain.scala:57)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tmt.TMTMain.main(TMTMain.scala)
```

Since, I have no idea how scala functions, I am not sure what is missing here and how I can successfully execute the PLDA script on the PubMed data.

Any hints or directions are appreciated.